# Pandas groupby is keeping other non-groupby columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a situation where in a Pandas groupby function, the dataframe is retaining all the other non-groupby fields, even though I want to discard them.

Here's the dataframe before the groupby:

| org_id | inspection | person_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | TRUE | 453241 | 1/1/23 |
| 222 | FALSE | 21341 | 6/1/23 |
| 333 | FALSE | 42343241 | 3/1/23 |
| 111 | FALSE | 098678 | 2/1/23 |
| 111 | TRUE | 6786 | 6/1/23 |
| 222 | TRUE | 546 | 4/1/23 |
| 333 | TRUE | vcxv313 | 4/1/23 |
| 222 | TRUE | 876 | 4/1/23 |
| 333 | TRUE | 432gf | 4/1/23 |

and my groupby function is being used as : `df.groupby(by=['org_id', 'inspection'], dropna=False).count()`

For some reason, it's keeping person_id and date in the output:

| org_id | inspection | person_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | TRUE | 2 | 2 |
| 222 | FALSE | 1 | 1 |
| 333 | FALSE | 1 | 1 |
| 111 | FALSE | 1 | 1 |
| 222 | TRUE | 2 | 2 |
| 333 | TRUE | 2 | 2 |

The counts are correct, but it's being noted in the two columns preserved from the original dataframe. I've tried reassigning the dataframe but that hasn't fixed anything. Is there a parameter I'm supposed to set to remove the two columns?

Comment: By including the aggfunc `.count()`, you are telling it that you want to groupby the first 2 columns and aggregate the other columns. What is your expected output if not to count the non-grouped columns?

Comment: ah I'm used to SQL, where the group by columns are designated, and a simple count can be called on the number of rows. So I was expecting a single column of the count of rows in each grouping

Comment: An understandable point of confusion. It's similar, except it includes all non-grouped numeric columns in the aggregattion instead of specifying which column you want to count. Perhaps you wanted, for example `df.groupby(by=['org_id', 'inspection'], dropna=False)[person_id].count()`

Answer (score 0):

## You could also use `pd.DataFrame.value_counts()` with specified column names to count occurrences

```py
df.value_counts(["org_id", "inspection"])
```

returns a multi-index `pd.Series` (single column) count:

```
org_id  inspection
111     TRUE          2
222     TRUE          2
333     TRUE          2
111     FALSE         1
222     FALSE         1
333     FALSE         1
dtype: int64
```

which is equivalent to a `.groupby` result (except opposite sorting of the resultant multi-index):
[image]

You could simply add `sort=False` to obtain identical results to the groupby:

```py
>>> df.value_counts(["org_id", "inspection"], sort=False)
org_id  inspection
111     FALSE         1
        TRUE          2
222     FALSE         1
        TRUE          2
333     FALSE         1
        TRUE          2
dtype: int64
```

in which case by removing the sort you actually get marginally faster speed now than the groupby:
[image: value counts no sort]